# How safe is sqlx compile time checks?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

If I understand correctly, it is possible for sqlx to do a form of compile time verification of queries. And the way it does this, is at compile time, it connects to the database using `DATABASE_URL` env variable and performs some checks against the database.

My question is, how does sqlx ensure safety? How does sqlx ensures that the verification does not actually mutates the database? I mean how does it handle checks for queries like delete, insert, update etc?

Comment: It doesn't execute the queries, it uses some protocol that only validates queries.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you know what protocol this is?

Answer (score 0):

SQLX doesn't check your queries in the flow of your program, it only checks for syntax erros if tables and rows exist.

Even with sqlx you still can get runtime erros, maybe the sql server stopped, or the schema changed.